# Apache httpd 2.2.x + mod_jk 1.2.30 + tomcat 6 Error: Could not find worker with name 'XXXXX' in uri map post processing

Tags: apache, tomcat6, mod-jk

I am getting the following error while setting up the load balancer with two Tomcat instances:

> [info] mod_jk.c (3189): mod_jk/1.2.30 initialized
>   [error] jk_uri_worker_map.c (506): Could not find worker with name 'loadmanager' in uri map post processing.

Following are my configuration settings:

httpd.conf changes

```
# Include mod_jk configuration file
Include conf/mod_jk.conf
```

mod_jk.conf

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so    
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties    
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log    
JkLogLevel info    
JkLogStampFormat  "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"    
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories    
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"    
JkMount /TestLB1/ loadmanager    
JkMount /TestLB1/* loadmanager    
JkShmFile logs/jk.shm
```

workers.properties

```
worker.list=loadmanager

worker.tomcat1.port=18081
worker.tomcat1.host=localhost
worker.tomcat1.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat1.lbfactor=1

worker.tomcat2.port=28081
worker.tomcat2.host=localhost
worker.tomcat2.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat2.lbfactor=1

worker.loadmanager.type=lb
worker.loadmanager.balance_workers=tomcat1,tomcat2
worker.loadmanager.sticky_session=True
```

In Tomcat's server.xml I have set the jvmRoute attribute to Engine also

```
 <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina" jvmRoute="tomcat1">
 <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina" jvmRoute="tomcat2">
```

Both the Tomcat instances are up and running fine with AJP ports 18081 & 28081 respectively.

But while starting the Apache httpd.exe the mod_jk log files always shows the above error, and when I try to access my web app through http://localhost/TestLB1 nothing comes up.

Any Solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the problem....
Issues is with the text editor in which i was editing my worker.properties file , it adds few special chars to files.
I found them when i opend the files in notepad only.
After removing all unwanted chars everythings works perfect.

Comment: +1 I was trying to follow along the JBoss AS clustering guide and kept seeing the same error.  It seems the mod_jk code running on a windows box was quietly failing to parse the workers.properties file because it wanted to see CRLFs at the end of lines instead of just CRs.  But instead of reporting a parsing error, it just vaguely says something is wrong with my configuration.  <groan>

Comment: Hi Pushkar, you mean notepad on Windows? Where were these special chars, at the end or among the lines?

Comment: yes on windows notepad spl chars were at the end of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Create your worker.properties file with a good text editor like notepad++. Not doing so may add some unseen special characters and workers.properties file wont parse by mod_jk.