# Apache Checking Status of Tomcat instance

Tags: apache, tomcat, load-balancing

I would like to be able to check that status of a tomcat instance when Apache is being called.

The ultimate goal is to have a non sticky environment, except for authentication. I have achieved the first portion of this task by using a path name and using SetEnvIfNoCase to check for the path name and set JK_WORKER_NAME to the appropriate tomcat instance. Now I have to deal with the server failure issue happening in the middle of the sticky authentication.

**The conditions of failure are as follows:**
1) Call Cas from Instance one and have path name set
2) Instance one fails while login process is being done
3) Cas returns to Apache which tries to direct to instance one which is down
4) Tomcat gives Service Not Available

What I would like to happen is at step 3 I want apache to check on the status or ping the tomcat instance to see if the server is still alive and if not change the JK_WORKER_NAME back to the load balanced worker.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243952/disable-stickyness-on-apache-mod-proxy-balancer/25337541#25337541 - You should look at this answer

Comment: That answer is not a safe option and a waste of an entire server for a situation that should not happen often since the window is narrow. Also, the redirect in the worker.properties was not working when I had a failure before. The workers were pointing at one another than at the loadbalancer. The issue is more that the workers are doing true redirects going back into apache, it seems, instead of forwarding the request to the next tomcat instance. If the redirect was actually a forward than I think the apache forcing to specific worker would not be a problem.